# aws-alb-ingress metrics on eks?

Tags: metrics, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm using the official aws-alb-ingress-controller for ingress + load balancing to my services hosted in an EKS cluster.

Does this offer metrics of any kind? Preferably Prometheus metrics? To show things like volume metrics etc?

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller

I don't see any mention of metrics in the docs, but metrics seems like a necessary part of any production load balancer.

Comment: Might be helpful to ask AWS Support directly. Also update us if they give you more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each [AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller) Pod
[Exposes](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/v1.1.4/cmd/main.go#L153) prometheus `/metrics` on the same port `10254` where it responds to `/healthz` checks.
Both endpoints are currently served with [the same mux](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/v1.1.4/cmd/main.go#L104-L107).

Comment: Interesting. This absolutely works. But it only exposes a few internal metrics and not metrics on the back end services like traffic volume, response latency, error rate, etc. But this is the answer. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, these are metrics of the ingress containers, that tell you how your ingress containers perform.

I guess you are more interested in API responses status codes, URLs and request duration.

I was looking into it hoping that I can build my SLIs and SLOs by capturing metrics directly from ingress. But I was not able to find these metrics in ALB.

My solution, for now, is to measure this on app-level in router middleware.
You can also switch to Nginx ingress and use this instrumentation: https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus

Comment: Another option that I've explored is switching from alb-ingress to istio. Istio provides full app-level metrics and lots of other features, but it adds complexity. alb is so very simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest option, AFAIK:

https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter

Answer (score 0):

The AWS ALB ingress controller is integrated with CloudWatch and provides various metrics. In CloudWatch you can do monitoring and alerting based on these metrics.

If your system uses Prometheus for this, you can any exporter to send the metrics to Prometheus. Another possible exporter would be: [YACE (Yet Another CloudWatch Exporter](https://github.com/nerdswords/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter).

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/monitor-aws-services-used-by-kubernetes-with-prometheus-and-promcat/) you can find an article from the AWS open source blog on how to setup an ELB with Prometheus metrics and Graphana on top with a custom dashboard. The configuration for an ALB is pretty similar. [Here](https://promcat.io/apps/aws-alb) you have the information on how to achieve this for an ALB.